# Image size not divisible by 2 for input shape VGG16

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, shapes

I have a dataset with images of different sizes.  I decided to use an image size of 115x115 because it's near average of every image size. I read that the image size should be divisible by 2 but I got good results in my model with 115x115 so I don't understand. Am I wrong with that size? Should I use another size divisible by 2?

Thank you and sorry if anyone has already asked this question before.

Comment: If it works well, why change it? You can always simply reshape to eg. 116x116 and see if there is any difference in performance/training time etc.

Comment: For classification models it arguably doesn't really matter. For models that also _output_ images (e.g. U-nets for segmentation), this is more important since the output size usually needs to match the input size, and if your input size is not divisible by 2 (or rather, a power of 2), this can be difficult to achieve.

Comment: My goal is to predict the class of a new image with VGG16 or Simple CNN.